# New dict of top n values (and keys) from dictionary (Python)

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of names and the number of times the names appear in the phone book:

```
names_dict = {
    'Adam': 100,
    'Anne': 400,
    'Britney': 321,
    'George': 645,
    'Joe': 200,
    'John': 1010,
    'Mike': 500,
    'Paul': 325,
    'Sarah': 150
}
```

Preferably without using `sorted()`, I want to iterate through the dictionary and create a new dictionary that has the top five names only:

```
def sort_top_list():
  # create dict of any 5 names first
  new_dict = {}
  for i in names_dict.keys()[:5]:
    new_dict[i] = names_dict[i]:

  # Find smallest current value in new_dict
  # and compare to others in names_dict
  # to find bigger ones; replace smaller name in new_dict with bigger name
  for k,v in address_dict.iteritems():
    current_smallest = min(new_dict.itervalues())
    if v > current_smallest:
      # Found a bigger value; replace smaller key/ value in new_dict with larger key/ value
      new_dict[k] = v
      # ?? delete old key/ value pair from new_dict somehow
```

I seem to be able to create a new dictionary that gets a new key/ value pair whenever we iterate through names_dict and find a name/ count that is higher than what we have in new_dict. I can't figure out, though, how to remove the smaller ones from new_dict after we add the bigger ones from names_dict.

Is there a better way - without having to import special libraries or use `sorted()` - to iterate through a dict and create a new dict of the top N keys with the highest values?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to use `sorted`?

Comment: It's just an exercise. I know sorted is used a ton but I wanted to see if it was possible without any 'extra' stuff like sorted (dictionary iterator if fine). I've seen some of the answers to questions like this on SO but they use sorted.

Comment: you could loop through the dict (or a hard copy of it) and pop the largest value every time, five times. Just remember to store the keys every time you replace your temp max

Comment: There's nothing to stop you doing it yourself.  You would probably just write your own sort and pass`d.items()` to it.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the [`heapq.nlargest()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) to achieve this:

```
import heapq
from operator import itemgetter

top_names = dict(heapq.nlargest(5, names_dict.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))
```

This uses a more efficient algorithm (O(NlogK) for a dict of size N, and K top items) to extract the top 5 items as `(key, value)` tuples, which are then passed to `dict()` to create a new dictionary.

Demo:

```
>>> import heapq
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> names_dict = {'Adam': 100, 'Anne': 400, 'Britney': 321, 'George': 645, 'Joe': 200, 'John': 1010, 'Mike': 500, 'Paul': 325, 'Sarah': 150}
>>> dict(heapq.nlargest(5, names_dict.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))
{'John': 1010, 'George': 645, 'Mike': 500, 'Anne': 400, 'Paul': 325}
```

You probably want to use the [`collections.Counter()` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead. The [`Counter.most_common()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) would have made your use-case trivial to solve. The implementation for that method uses `heapq.nlargest()` under the hood.

These are *not* special libraries, they are part of the Python standard library. You otherwise would have to implement a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) yourself to achieve this. Unless you are specifically studying this algorithm, there is little point in re-implementing your own, the [Python implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/heapq.py) is highly optimised with an [extension written in C](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Modules/_heapqmodule.c) for some critical functions).

Comment: they appear to be sorted but that is not actually true in the general case, right? this is afterall just a dict. Also why not `Collections.Ordereddict(sorted(...))`? Is it because you would have to "slice" it afterwards by jumping to a `list` and then back?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I used Python 3.6 where the new dict implementation happens to preserve input order.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that. Maybe it's worth mentioning! Thanks. +1

Comment: @Ev.Kounis sorted has to do more work as it has to put all elements in order, not just the top 5.

Comment: I would expect `nlargest` to do the same internally. To find the top five you have to check them all but you are right, you don't have to sort the remaining ones at least.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm wondering if there is a way to do it without importing anything at all. I know that is not how you would probably do it in practice, and your answer is correct, but this is just an exercise for me and I'm hoping there is a way to do this without importing anything.

Comment: @kevingduck: as I said, you could implement a heap yourself. It is not *that* hard, the [`heapq` module source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/heapq.py) is available.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: do study up on heaps and the [time complexity of algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). The Python sort algorithm, [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), is an O(NlogN) algorithm, meaning that as the size N of the input list tends to infinity, order N log N steps need to be taken to sort the list.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: A heap takes O(logK) to insert an item in a heap size of size K; it doesn't keep that heap sorted, just in *heap order*, which is almost but not quite the same thing. But inserting a new item is cheap, and only the top K items are kept each time (so the smallest is ejected from the heap). You only need to do this N times, so finding the top K items takes O(N log K) time. Because K < N, using a heapq to find the top K items should *generally* be faster than using sorting.

Comment: @kevingduck: there are also far less efficient ways to do this of course; a heap just happens to be the most efficient. For a far worse performing algorithm, you could use `max_key = max(names_dict, key=names_dict.get); results[max_key] = names_dict.pop(max_key)` five times in a loop (with `results = {}` before the loop). That is worse because `max()` has to examine all values of the `names_dict` for each iteration, so it takes O(KN) time.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, why you don't want to use sort and the solution is not perfect and even doesn't match your problem exactly, but I hope it can inspire you to find your own implementation. I think it was only a short example for the real Problem you have.

But as you have seen on the other answer: Normally it is better to use code, that is written before instead of do all the things yourself.

```
names_dict = {'Joe' : 200, 'Anne': 400, 'Mike': 500, 'John': 1010, 'Sarah': 150, 'Paul': 325, 'George' : 645, 'Adam' : 100, 'Britney': 321}

def extract_top_n(dictionary, count):
    #first step: Find the topmost values
    highest_values = []
    for k,v in dictionary.iteritems():
        print k,v, highest_values, len(highest_values)
        highest_values.append(v)
        l = len(highest_values)
        for i in range(l-1):
            print i,l
            if l-i < 1:
                break
            if highest_values[l-i-1]>highest_values[l-i-2]:
                temp = highest_values[l-i-2]
                highest_values[l-i-2] = highest_values[l-i-1]
                highest_values[l-i-1] = temp
        highest_values = highest_values [:count]

    #fill the dirctionary with all entries at least as big as the smallest of the biggest
    #but pay attention: If there are more than 2 occurances of one of the top N there will be more than N entries in the dictionary
    last_interesting = highest_values[len(highest_values)-1]
    return_dictionary = {}    
    for k,v in dictionary.iteritems():
        if v >= last_interesting:
            return_dictionary[k] = v
    return return_dictionary

print extract_top_n(names_dict,3)
```